# 3.3v led and 220v water pump

Tags: led, resistors, motor

I have relay connected to raspberry pi that switches the water pump on and off. I would like to add a toggle switch before the relay with a led. When the switch is turned on the led lights up and then the relay can turn the pump on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3juxS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- C1 limits diode current to roughly 10 mA RMS, half through D1, half through D2
- R1 provides some surge protection for LED
- R2 discharges C1 for safety

Pay attention to peak voltage ratings on C1, R2!